# Why are blocks of images getting pixelated when extracted but become normal when concatenated?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I am splitting a 200x200 image into 16 50x50 images but 2 of those images are pixelated and the wrong color

```
img = cv2.imread('nothingZ.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
windowsize_r = 50
windowsize_c = 50
window = []                                                      
for r in range(0,gray.shape[0], windowsize_r):
 for c in range(0,gray.shape[0], windowsize_c):
  window.append(gray[r:r+windowsize_r,c:c+windowsize_c])
for i, el in enumerate(window):
 array2 = np.moveaxis(window[i], 0, 0)    
 plt.subplot(4, 4, i + 1)
 plt.imshow(array2, 'gray')     
plt.show()
vis2 = np.concatenate((window[4], window[5], window[6]), axis=1)
plt.imshow(vis2,'gray')
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/DiRYfww The original. https://i.imgur.com/maL5mdS.png The split image. https://i.imgur.com/bo7ZsAO.png The concatenated image

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please do not supply additional information in comments, but update the Question  with an [edit] instead. Read [ask] for more information.

Comment: What's with the `moveaxis` call? Why not just `for el in window: imshow(el, 'gray')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that your image is getting automatically normalized in plotting. That would be why in certain regions (where it's all roughly uniform in color) the values get stretched out to each extreme, highlighting the pixelations from the jpeg compression. But then when concatenated, it has the dark colors from the border so the colors don't get blown out.

For clarity, this means that your blocks *aren't* pixelated, they are just being displayed to you that way in `matplotlib`.

To normalize all your images the same, use the `vmin` and `vmax` arguments in `plt.imshow()`. From the [`imshow()` docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html):

> **vmin, vmax** : scalar, optional
>   When using scalar data and no explicit norm, *vmin* and *vmax* define the data range that the colormap covers. **By default, the colormap covers the complete value range of the supplied data.** *vmin*, *vmax* are ignored if the norm parameter is used.

Emphasis added by me.

In other words, the lowest value of your image gets set to black, and the highest value to white. If your image has only the values 123, 125, 127, 129, 131, that means that they (effectively) get mapped to the brightness values 0, 51, 102, 153, 204, 255 (or around there). So things that are close in color get blown out to quite different colors. Normally the jpeg compression artifacts are not too visible since the colors are similar, but when stretching it out, it is very obvious.

To use the arguments and fix your plotting issue, replace

```
plt.imshow(array2, 'gray')
```

with

```
plt.imshow(array2, 'gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
```